# Error: syntax error at or near "(" .Problem: cannot create a table

Tags: sql

I just tried to create a table, here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE new_final_assignment (
  item_id         VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  test_assignment INT(10),
  test_number     VARCHAR(32),
  test_start_date VARCHAR(32)
);
```

And this is the error:

> `ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
>     Position: 268
>     item_id         VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>     test_assignment INT(10),
>                        ^
>     test_number     VARCHAR(32),`.

I just don't know where I'm wrong. The default_read_only statement is off as I confirmed.
Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Which rdbms system are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc). Not all of them support size specifiers on integers, so it's possible you've copied syntax from one that does to one that doesn't.

Comment: @Damien My guess is either Oracle or MySQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: assuming MySQL (which is the only DBMS that supports something like `int(10)` to my knowledge) that's actually not a "size specifier" - it's a hint for an application displaying the value on how to format the value.

Comment: Thank you, I do use the MySQL DBMS. So how should I handle this problem to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

`INT` Doesn't have user defined length. So, removed it.:

```
CREATE TABLE new_final_assignment (
  item_id         VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  test_assignment INT, -- Length is not required 
  test_number     VARCHAR(32),
  test_start_date VARCHAR(32)
);
```

Comment: If I remove the length, then it displays ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction. This is very tricky because the default_read_only function is off .